# HTML Picture Display Error

Tags: html, css

I programmed the following website using a template and some sample pictures: http://arianeschaefer.16mb.com/testsite/fashion.html

As you can see the last three pictures don't get displayed correctly.

I first thought it was because the nav-bar is too short, but that was not the issue. Anyone got any suggestions of what i could try.

The complete code is uploaded here:
    https://pastebin.com/Xf3Bi9ju
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Please explain the code you’ve tried and give us short to the point examples of it

Comment: Bascially i used the same piece of code for every single image. It formats it depending on the size of the image. I just tried to add 14 images, but after the 9th one it stopped displaying them. And i have no clue at all why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed the `src` attribute value in the HTML:

```
<img src="assets/img/fashion/Fashion9.jpg alt=" pro1"="">
```

You are missing the closing double quote, it should be:

```
<img src="assets/img/fashion/Fashion9.jpg" alt="" pro1="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it displays the pictures now. If you visit the website again you see that it does not align them next to one another any more. Also, do you know why it worked for the first 9 pictures with that error.

Comment: Web browsers  do a lot of work behind the scenes to recover from HTML errors. Some errors are not recoverable...

Comment: So there is no way of aligning them next to each other?

Comment: Check the style on those images, you do not have any positionning on the last few. You are using absolute positionning for the other images, so you must apply the same technique for those last ones.

Comment: Does the absolute positioning happen in the CSS-Files or in the HTML? If it happens in CSS i have a problem because there is 8 files coming with this template. (Sorry for all these questions but this was supposed to be a present for my sister and none of my friends were able to help me)